# Why can I find the member of the original variable and not the assigned variable?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

So I recognize that the question title is a little cryptic, but basically I'm wondering why I can't get the same value for result.name and facebookUserData.name? I can only seem to get an answer from result.name and not from facebookUserData.name. I'm completely baffled as to why not.

```
FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({(connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (result? != nil) {
            NSLog("error = \(error)")
            var facebookUserData = result as FBGraphObject
            println(result.name)
        }
        } as FBRequestHandler)
```

In addition, I'm curious as to how I would "escape" from within this code, i.e. if I wanted to use the value held in facebookUserData outside of FBRequestConnection.

Comment: To use the data outside of the closure, instead of assigning `result` to a local variable, assign it to a property

Comment: you never reference facebookUserData after creating it. depending on how swift is optimized it may get released instantly.